# Display current monitor refresh rate (FreeSync test)

Tags: windows-10, display, nvidia-graphics-card, g-sync

Is there any way to display the current monitor refresh rate? I have a monitor that supports FreeSync, and an Nvidia graphics card on Windows 10. I have enabled G-Sync compatible in Nvidia Settings, and I am playing a 24fps video.

I want to see the current monitor refresh rate (I mean the dynamic one set by FreeSync, not the nominal 60Hz in Windows settings), because I want to know if the current monitor rate is reduced to 24fps. Is this possible?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The monitor refresh rate never changes once it's set. Are you looking for the currently effective fps? If yes, then this should come from your video player.

Comment: @harrymc G-SYNC and Freesync are Variable Refresh Rate systems. They can change refresh rate to match FPS for a smoother experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvidia has the following to say on [How to know if G-SYNC is enabled](https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nvdsp/To_know_if_VRR_is_turned_on_in_your_game.htm):

> To verify whether G-SYNC is enabled for your game, click **Display**
> from the NVIDIA Control Panel menu bar, then select **Show indicator
> for G-SYNC**.
>
> **Note**: Depending on the type of monitor connected, the menu item could state **Show indicator for G-SYNC, Show indicator for G-SYNC
> Compatible, or Show indicator for G-SYNC/G-SYNC Compatible**
>
> The indicator will appear on your screen to let you know whether
> G-SYNC is turned on.

Additionally i'd like to mention Freesync typically has a bottom range of 40Hz, not allowing you to have native 24Hz support. I'm unsure of wether it will switch to 48Hz as a best alternative.